# Using cloud-native buildpacks with Spring Boot < 2.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, buildpack, paketo

Spring Boot 2.3 introduced support for building optimized Docker images using the Spring Boot maven/gradle plugin. The `spring-boot:build-image` goal does a bunch of things:

- Create the layers index
- Invoke the Paketo buildpack
- Build the OCI image
- etc.

Is there a way to replicate these steps for modules using an older Spring Boot version? Even better, can these steps be integrated directly into a maven/gradle build?

Comment: You can use `pack build`, https://github.com/buildpacks/pack, with the Java meta CNB, https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/java, to generate optimized images for Java apps. The Spring Boot 2.3 integration is utilizing these buildpacks. I'm not sure that'll get you 100% of the optimizations Spring Boot is doing, but it should get you a well-built image based on the Paketo buildpacks.

Comment: @DanielMikusa, does that include the layer detection/optimization provided by the Spring Boot plugin?

Comment: Not sure exactly, I would suggest building images both ways and comparing them. You can use `dive` or something similar to compare the layers. https://github.com/wagoodman/dive

Answer (score 1):

As the layered jars feature (incl. `layers.idx` file generation and spring-boot-maven-plugin support for Cloud Native Buildpacks / Paketo.io) [was introduced in Spring Boot 2.3](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/creating-efficient-docker-images-with-spring-boot-2-3) I would say that you can't really downgrade it with the standard tooling.

BUT I guess you could try to generate the `layers.idx` file yourself - or even choose a default file, since the layout of your app may not change that much after all. A example would be (using no `SNAPSHOT` depencencies):

```
- "dependencies":
  - "BOOT-INF/lib/"
- "spring-boot-loader":
  - "org/"
- "snapshot-dependencies":
- "application":
  - "BOOT-INF/classes/"
  - "BOOT-INF/classpath.idx"
  - "BOOT-INF/layers.idx"
  - "META-INF/"
```

Having this file in place (means place it into your `target` folder (maybe you could automate that with a simple Maven plugin for example)), pack CLI should be able to pick it up. So [install pack CLI](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/) and run a Paketo build without using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` yourself like this:

```
pack build yourAppNameHere --path . --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base
```

I didn't really tried this approach myself - and maybe you run into problems, if the directory structure is much different in older Spring Boot versions. But I would appreciate to hear some feedback!